# MongoDB $currentOp.twoPhaseCommitCoordinator.action

Tags: mongodb, nosql, distributed-computing

I am trying to understand what the following operations do, do not need al the details; just a global view of each of the operations. Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol

Comment: Of course Wikipedia was my first source but it does not talk about these operations in particular it just explains the generalities of the 2PC protocol.